# Is the [homonymy] tag supposed to be for same pronunciation and spelling, or just either?

Tags: discussion, tags

Is [homonymy](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homonymy) supposed to be for same pronunciation *and* spelling, or just either?

The tag guidance says:

> a relation between a group of words that share the same spelling and the same pronunciation but have different meanings

I was going to use it to ask if there was an unambiguous way to differentiate between the two P.I.E "*ster-" variations I found, but I wasn't sure if it was the right tag. Also, [homophony](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homophony) exists but without tag wiki.

([Strand's etymology](https://proto_roots.en-academic.com/1892/ster-4) and [Sterile's etymology](https://proto_roots.en-academic.com/1894/ster-6). Wiktionary's using [the second](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/ster-), currently.)

Comment: _Homonymy_ is the state of being a homonym. The question is what _homonym_ means, and whether it refers to spelling or pronunciation. So, _bear_ (v), _bear_ (n), _bare_ (adj): one, two, or three homonyms?

Comment: The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homonym) made it more complex: homograph, homophone, *or both*.

Comment: Homophonograph?

Answer (score 4):

I've heard the terms *homophone* for the same pronunciation, *homograph* for the same orthography, and *homonym* for both. And we do have a separate [homophony](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homophony) tag.

But personally, I don't think we need three separate tags for this. Neither is very widely used, and for things like Proto-Indo-European (which has no native orthography), one always implies the other. I wouldn't object to merging the two and having it used for any of the three meanings.

Comment: Yeah, like _antonym, homonym_ is an ill-defined term. Being a linguist, I would use it as equivalent to _homophone_, since only the pronunciation (and not the spelling) matters.